# Powershell search for pattern with itextsharp.dll

Tags: powershell, itext

I need to search pdf-files for patterns and then I just want the name of the files containing "region värmland", using that to copy the files to a different folder.

The pattern is in the top right corner, and if possible I would like to search as little as possible in the file due the number of files.

I could not find any relevant information when googleing how to just search for one set of words and keep the output inside the script for further use.

Anyone who can help with this?

Comment: Noone can help?